# How can I change the shutter speed when taking a picture with my Google Pixel 6?

Tags: camera, images, android-12, google-pixel-6

I use a  Google Pixel 6 with Android 12. How can I change the shutter speed when taking a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the shutter speed when taking a picture is not possible with the default camera application on a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12. However, one can use this mod: https://www.celsoazevedo.com/files/android/google-camera/dev-MWP/ (root not needed).

[image]

On the left side, bottom part, there's an option to change the exposure time.

There's a native long exposure mode:

[image]

[image]